# IE8 losing session details

Tags: java, session, internet-explorer-8

I have a Java web app that intermittently loses session data. The problem only occurs with users on IE8. I have used IEWatch to monitor the http traffic, and it seems that the correct session cookies are being sent (JSESSIONID2). 
When the request gets to the server the session has become unbound from the custom session monitor (this uses HttpBindingListener). 
As I have mentioned this problem is intermittent and I have even gone through a transaction with the customer doing exactly the same thing on my machine - however I was unable to replicate their problem. It should also be noted that the transaction fails at the same point every time for all users experiencing this - it one the second page of a 4 page wizard type transaction. 
Any help will be gratefully received.

Nige

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I did find the problem.

I use DWR for AJAX stuff and there is an issue with DWRUtil.useLoadingMessage().

See http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/browser/util/useLoadingMessage.html

So this caused an execption, which went to an error page (jsp) which had an invalidate session statement on it.

Took me bloody ages to find it.

I hope this helps you, but I somehow doubt it :)

Nige